# Shell variable to get Python bin directory?

Tags: python, shell, pip

On Mac OS X, when I install a Python package from `pip` using `--user`, the binary installs to:

```
/Users/mike/Library/Python/2.7/bin
```

Is there a shell variable I can use to get the location of this directory? I'm trying to make some instructions for per-user installs that work across OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a shell variable as far as I'm aware but you could try something like this:

```
pyver=$(pip -V | cut -f6 -d" " | cut -c 1-3)
dir=$HOME/Library/Python/$pyver/bin
```

The first line there will get the 'default' version of Python (2.7 in  your case) and the second will make a dir on the format you presented.

Comment: `which python` refers to the location of the `python` binary. Egm on my system that's /usr/bin/python. This is not what the question is asking.

Comment: @mikemaccana Absolutely, I had misunderstood the question. I'm on my phone currently, but I wrote that little snippet, let me know if it works. I'll test it as soon as I get to work today.

Comment: @mikemaccana Tested and fixed.